# React component causes "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server"

Tags: reactjs, hydration

I have a custom skeleton component that accepts some parameters. But I don't understand why using it causes a hydration error: "Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

**skeleton.tsx**

```
interface SkeletonProps {
    width?: number;
    height?: number;
    count?: number;
    className?: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties;
    inline?: boolean;
}

export default function Skeleton({className, width, height, count, style, inline} : SkeletonProps)  {
    const skeletonStyles = {
        width: width ? `${width}px` : '100%',
        height: height ? `${height}px` : '',
    }

    return (
        <>
        
         { Array(count ? count : 1).fill(0).map(item=> {
            return (
                <>
                <div className={`skeleton ${className ? className : ''}`} style={{...skeletonStyles, ...style}}>
                    ‌
                </div>
                {inline ? '' : <br />}
                </>
            )
        }) }
        </>
    )

}
```

**Usage example**

```
<Skeleton height={190} />
```

I tried to remove custom parameters from it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `NoSsr` like

```
<NoSsr>
  <Skeleton height={190} />
</NoSsr>
```

npm reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-no-ssr

Hope it may be helpful.